# Why g++ O2 option make unsigned wrap around not working?

Tags: c++, g++, unsigned-integer

I was trying to write a queue with c++, and I learn from intel dpdk libring that I can do that by writing codes like that using the unsigned wrap around property:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

size_t global_r = 0, global_w = 0, mask_ = 3;

void emplace() {
  unsigned long local_w, local_r, free_entries = 0;
  local_w = global_w;
  while (free_entries == 0) {
    local_r = global_r;
    free_entries = (mask_ + local_r - local_w);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "%lu\n", free_entries);
  auto w_next = local_w + 1;
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  global_w = w_next;
}

void pop() {
  unsigned long local_r = global_r;
  unsigned long r_next = local_r + 1;
  // make sure nobody can write to it before destruction
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  global_r = r_next;
}

int main() {
  std::jthread([]() -> void {
    int i = 10;
    while (i-- >= 0) emplace();
  });
  std::jthread([]() -> void {
    int i = 10;
    while (i-- >= 0) pop();
  });
  return 0;
}
```

when I run it with g++ O0 and O2, it produce different results:
with O2:

```
3
2
1
0
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551614
18446744073709551613
18446744073709551612
18446744073709551611
18446744073709551610
18446744073709551609
```

without O2:

```
3
2
1
.....long time suspending
```

I wonder is there any wrong with my understanding of unsinged wrap around? (I learn from several stackoverflow post and other references that unsinged wrap around is defined behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that once `global_w` is incremented to 3 then the `while` loop in `emplace()` becomes an infinite loop? AFAIK, infinite loops result in *undefined behavior* in C++.

I believe your problem comes from the fact that you define `std::jthread` objects as temporaries. This means that they are destructed at the end of expression where they emerge. Consequently, both threads do not run in parallel (at the same time).

You can easily change that by creating thread variables, which will be destructed at the end of `main()`:

```
int main()
{
  std::thread t1 ([]() -> void {  // note that "t1" variable name
    int i = 10;
    while (i-- >= 0) emplace();
  });

  std::thread t2 ([]() -> void {  // note that "t2" variable name
    int i = 10;
    while (i-- >= 0) pop();
  });
}
```

However, even then, I think you have a *data race* on `global_r`, which results in *undefined behavior* as well. Without its synchronized writes, a compiler may easily suppose that `emplace()` has exclusive access to `global_r` and effectively "remove" this read `local_r = global_r;` from the loop.

Live demo of this type of problem: https://godbolt.org/z/566WP9n36.

Comment: thank you very much，I haven‘ t think about that infinite loop and data races as UB before，I just modeled after the ring code in dpdk，seems I ’ve missed some key code pieces of synchronization.